# Unable to reach IIS Express folder from solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, iis

I’m trying to learn how to deserialize and serialize JSON, but the current directory which my web application outputs the json-file after serialization of my objects; is in the c:/user/ProgramFiles(x86)/IISExpress/-folder.

I am unable to reach the json-file which I have manually moved to my App_Data-folder as it says “it cannot find file”.
It also gives me “Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Output.json' is denied.” For some reason.

How would I go about solving the map-path as I have tried in my code to direct me to the right directory within the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to deserialize json from a file from App_Data, I believe you could put everything in a variable like this:

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(“/App_Data/Output.json”));
```

The reason it gives you the “Access to the path X is denied”, is because you are not running Visual Studio as an administrator.
Try right-clicking the VS-icon and click “Run as administrator”, and try again.